# valueError could not convert string to floatPython 2.7

Tags: python, numpy

I had this code on python 2.7.5 :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
#Ejercicio 24

from numpy import *
from string import *

def main():
i=0
j=0
k=0
filas=5
temp=''
columnas=3
nombres=['Julio' , 'Andres', 'Cesar', 'Maria', 'Isabel']
print nombres
tabla= arange(15)
tabla=tabla.reshape(filas,columnas)
print tabla

for j in range(columnas):
    for i in range(filas):
        if j==0:
            temp=nombres[i]
            #print temp
                    tabla[j,i]=int(float32(temp))
            print tabla[j,i]


return 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

Where I have a list containing strings(names) but I want to asign these names for the first column of the array called tabla.But i get this error in compiler:

```
['Julio', 'Andres', 'Cesar', 'Maria', 'Isabel']
[[ 0  1  2]
[ 3  4  5]
[ 6  7  8]
[ 9 10 11]
[12 13 14]]
Julio
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ejercicio24.py", line 34, in <module>
 main()
File "ejercicio24.py", line 25, in main
tabla[j,i]=int(float32(temp))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: Julio
```

Can I assign string for an specific column of an array?

Comment: What you wanna do? You have nothing but mistakes!

Comment: @scriptmonster I just want tocreate a 3x3 array with the first column of the array have asigned each element of the list "nombres" printing what I want is:

Comment: [[ Julio  1  2]
    [ Andres  4  5]
    [Cesar  7  8]
    [Maria 10 11]
    [Isabel 13 14]]

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of NumPy is to deal efficiently with arrays of one, usually numeric, data type. If the rows of an array have names, you would keep track of them in a separate array or a regular Python list.

Answer (score 0):

But how do you think 'Julio' can be converted to float32?
You can just type:

```
if j==0:
    temp=nombres[i]
    #print temp
    tabla[j,i]=temp
    print tabla[j,i]
```

Comment: Yes I know but i was try to asssign a string type elemnt of a list in a numeric 3x3 array in the first column only